# Unattended Offline Edubuntu 14.04 Install

Tags: system-installation, preseed, offline, edubuntu, kickstart

I am looking for a way to do this offline with Edubuntu 14.04 desktop. It would install much faster and better for large-scale deployments. It seems that contrary to some guides, kickstart is no longer required. These resources got me really close.

- [How to create a Customized Ubuntu Server ISO?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409607/how-to-create-a-customized-ubuntu-server-iso)
- [How do I create a completely unattended install of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122505/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu)
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation
- https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed
- https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/48919/Preseed-for-Trusty-Thrall---14-04-LTS

I have gotten pretty far with the Edubuntu ISO and the following files.

isolinux/isolinux.cfg

```
# D-I config version 2.0
include menu.cfg
default vesamenu.c32
prompt 0
timeout 30
ui gfxboot bootlogo
```

isolinux/txt.cfg

```
default unattended-EBA-install
label unattended-EBA-install
  menu label ^Install for EBA unattended
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/EBA.seed keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=us and console-setup/ask_detect=false boot=casper automatic-ubiquity noprompt initrd=/casper/initrd.lz --
label live
  menu label ^Try Edubuntu without installing
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/edubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --
label live-install
  menu label ^Install Edubuntu
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/edubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --
label check
  menu label ^Check disc for defects
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi
  append  boot=casper integrity-check initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --
label memtest
  menu label Test ^memory
  kernel /install/mt86plus
label hd
  menu label ^Boot from first hard disk
  localboot 0x80
```

preseed/EBA.seed

```
#### Contents of the preconfiguration file by Kevin McCormack for Edubuntu 14.04
### Localization
# Preseeding only locale sets language, country and locale.
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US

# Keyboard selection
# Disable automatic (interactive) keymap detection.
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select us
#d-i console-setup/layoutcode string us
# d-i keyboard-configuration/toggle select No toggling
#d-i keyboard-configuration keyboard-configuration/layoutcode string us
#d-i keyboard-configuration keyboard-configuration/layout select English (US)
#d-i keyboard-configuration keyboard-configuration/variant select English (US)
#d-i keyboard-configuration keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select us

### Network configuration
# Disable network configuration entirely. This is useful for cdrom
# installations on non-networked devices where the network questions,
# warning and long timeouts are a nuisance.
d-i netcfg/enable boolean false

# netcfg will choose an interface that has link if possible. This makes it
# skip displaying a list if there is more than one interface.
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto

# To pick a particular interface instead:
#d-i netcfg/choose_interface select eth1

# To set a different link detection timeout (default is 3 seconds).
# Values are interpreted as seconds.
#d-i netcfg/link_wait_timeout string 10

# If you have a slow dhcp server and the installer times out waiting for
# it, this might be useful.
#d-i netcfg/dhcp_timeout string 60
#d-i netcfg/dhcpv6_timeout string 60

# If you prefer to configure the network manually, uncomment this line and
# the static network configuration below.
#d-i netcfg/disable_autoconfig boolean true

# If you want the preconfiguration file to work on systems both with and
# without a dhcp server, uncomment these lines and the static network
# configuration below.
#d-i netcfg/dhcp_failed note
#d-i netcfg/dhcp_options select Configure network manually

# Static network configuration.
#
# IPv4 example
#d-i netcfg/get_ipaddress string 192.168.1.42
#d-i netcfg/get_netmask string 255.255.255.0
#d-i netcfg/get_gateway string 192.168.1.1
#d-i netcfg/get_nameservers string 192.168.1.1
#d-i netcfg/confirm_static boolean true
#
# IPv6 example
#d-i netcfg/get_ipaddress string fc00::2
#d-i netcfg/get_netmask string ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
#d-i netcfg/get_gateway string fc00::1
#d-i netcfg/get_nameservers string fc00::1
#d-i netcfg/confirm_static boolean true

# Any hostname and domain names assigned from dhcp take precedence over
# values set here. However, setting the values still prevents the questions
# from being shown, even if values come from dhcp.
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string unassigned-hostname
#d-i netcfg/get_hostname string "$(cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_asset_tag)"
#d-i netcfg/get_hostname string $(cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_name)
d-i netcfg/get_domain string unassigned-domain

# If you want to force a hostname, regardless of what either the DHCP
# server returns or what the reverse DNS entry for the IP is, uncomment
# and adjust the following line.
#d-i netcfg/hostname string somehost

# Disable that annoying WEP key dialog.
d-i netcfg/wireless_wep string
# The wacky dhcp hostname that some ISPs use as a password of sorts.
#d-i netcfg/dhcp_hostname string radish

# If non-free firmware is needed for the network or other hardware, you can
# configure the installer to always try to load it, without prompting. Or
# change to false to disable asking.
#d-i hw-detect/load_firmware boolean true

### Network console
# Use the following settings if you wish to make use of the network-console
# component for remote installation over SSH. This only makes sense if you
# intend to perform the remainder of the installation manually.
#d-i anna/choose_modules string network-console
#d-i network-console/authorized_keys_url string http://10.0.0.1/openssh-key
#d-i network-console/password password r00tme
#d-i network-console/password-again password r00tme

### Mirror settings
# If you select ftp, the mirror/country string does not need to be set.
#d-i mirror/protocol string ftp
#d-i mirror/country string manual
#d-i mirror/http/hostname string http.us.debian.org
#d-i mirror/http/directory string /debian
#d-i mirror/http/proxy string

# Suite to install.
#d-i mirror/suite string testing
# Suite to use for loading installer components (optional).
#d-i mirror/udeb/suite string testing

### Account setup
# Skip creation of a root account (normal user account will be able to
# use sudo).
#d-i passwd/root-login boolean false
# Alternatively, to skip creation of a normal user account.
#d-i passwd/make-user boolean false

# Root password, either in clear text
#d-i passwd/root-password password r00tme
#d-i passwd/root-password-again password r00tme
# or encrypted using an MD5 hash.
#d-i passwd/root-password-crypted password [MD5 hash]

# To create a normal user account.
d-i passwd/user-fullname string EBA Tech
d-i passwd/username string eba
# Normal user's password, either in clear text
#d-i passwd/user-password password insecure
#d-i passwd/user-password-again password insecure
# or encrypted using an MD5 hash.
d-i passwd/user-password-crypted password $1$jofdV3Qt$MhQLCV8ollmdpIazbibYZ/
# Create the first user with the specified UID instead of the default.
#d-i passwd/user-uid string 1010

# The user account will be added to some standard initial groups. To
# override that, use this.
#d-i passwd/user-default-groups string audio cdrom video

### Clock and time zone setup
# Controls whether or not the hardware clock is set to UTC.
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true

# You may set this to any valid setting for $TZ; see the contents of
# /usr/share/zoneinfo/ for valid values.
d-i time/zone string US/Eastern

# Controls whether to use NTP to set the clock during the install
d-i clock-setup/ntp boolean true
# NTP server to use. The default is almost always fine here.
#d-i clock-setup/ntp-server string ntp.example.com

### Partitioning
## Partitioning example
# If the system has free space you can choose to only partition that space.
# This is only honoured if partman-auto/method (below) is not set.
#d-i partman-auto/init_automatically_partition select biggest_free

# Alternatively, you may specify a disk to partition. If the system has only
# one disk the installer will default to using that, but otherwise the device
# name must be given in traditional, non-devfs format (so e.g. /dev/sda
# and not e.g. /dev/discs/disc0/disc).
# For example, to use the first SCSI/SATA hard disk:
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
# In addition, you'll need to specify the method to use.
# The presently available methods are:
# - regular: use the usual partition types for your architecture
# - lvm:     use LVM to partition the disk
# - crypto:  use LVM within an encrypted partition
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm

# If one of the disks that are going to be automatically partitioned
# contains an old LVM configuration, the user will normally receive a
# warning. This can be preseeded away...
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
# The same applies to pre-existing software RAID array:
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
# And the same goes for the confirmation to write the lvm partitions.
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

# You can choose one of the three predefined partitioning recipes:
# - atomic: all files in one partition
# - home:   separate /home partition
# - multi:  separate /home, /var, and /tmp partitions
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic

# Or provide a recipe of your own...
# If you have a way to get a recipe file into the d-i environment, you can
# just point at it.
#d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe_file string /hd-media/recipe

# If not, you can put an entire recipe into the preconfiguration file in one
# (logical) line. This example creates a small /boot partition, suitable
# swap, and uses the rest of the space for the root partition:
#d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
#      boot-root ::                                            \
#              40 50 100 ext3                                  \
#                      $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
#                      method{ format } format{ }              \
#                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext3 }    \
#                      mountpoint{ /boot }                     \
#              .                                               \
#              500 10000 1000000000 ext3                       \
#                      method{ format } format{ }              \
#                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext3 }    \
#                      mountpoint{ / }                         \
#              .                                               \
#              64 512 300% linux-swap                          \
#                      method{ swap } format{ }                \
#              .

# The full recipe format is documented in the file partman-auto-recipe.txt
# included in the 'debian-installer' package or available from D-I source
# repository. This also documents how to specify settings such as file
# system labels, volume group names and which physical devices to include
# in a volume group.

# This makes partman automatically partition without confirmation, provided
# that you told it what to do using one of the methods above.
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true


## Controlling how partitions are mounted
# The default is to mount by UUID, but you can also choose "traditional" to
# use traditional device names, or "label" to try filesystem labels before
# falling back to UUIDs.
#d-i partman/mount_style select uuid

### Base system installation
# Configure APT to not install recommended packages by default. Use of this
# option can result in an incomplete system and should only be used by very
# experienced users.
#d-i base-installer/install-recommends boolean false

# The kernel image (meta) package to be installed; "none" can be used if no
# kernel is to be installed.
#d-i base-installer/kernel/image string linux-image-586




### Apt setup
# You can choose to install restricted and universe software, or to install
# software from the backports repository.
d-i apt-setup/restricted boolean true
d-i apt-setup/universe boolean true
#d-i apt-setup/backports boolean true
# Uncomment this if you don't want to use a network mirror.
#d-i apt-setup/use_mirror boolean false
# Select which update services to use; define the mirrors to be used.
# Values shown below are the normal defaults.
#d-i apt-setup/services-select multiselect security
#d-i apt-setup/security_host string security.ubuntu.com
#d-i apt-setup/security_path string /ubuntu

# Additional repositories, local[0-9] available
#d-i apt-setup/local0/repository string \
#       http://local.server/ubuntu &releasename; main
#d-i apt-setup/local0/comment string local server
# Enable deb-src lines
#d-i apt-setup/local0/source boolean true
# URL to the public key of the local repository; you must provide a key or
# apt will complain about the unauthenticated repository and so the
# sources.list line will be left commented out
#d-i apt-setup/local0/key string http://local.server/key

# By default the installer requires that repositories be authenticated
# using a known gpg key. This setting can be used to disable that
# authentication. Warning: Insecure, not recommended.
#d-i debian-installer/allow_unauthenticated string true

### Package selection
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-edu-secondary
tasksel tasksel/first   seen false


# Individual additional packages to install
d-i pkgsel/include string openssh-server
# Policy for applying updates. May be "none" (no automatic updates),
# "unattended-upgrades" (install security updates automatically), or
# "landscape" (manage system with Landscape).
d-i pkgsel/update-policy select unattended-upgrades
# Enable extras.ubuntu.com.
d-i apt-setup/extras    boolean true

# Some versions of the installer can report back on what software you have
# installed, and what software you use. The default is not to report back,
# but sending reports helps the project determine what software is most
# popular and include it on CDs.
#popularity-contest popularity-contest/participate boolean false

### Boot loader installation
# Grub is the default boot loader (for x86). If you want lilo installed
# instead, uncomment this:
#d-i grub-installer/skip boolean true
# To also skip installing lilo, and install no bootloader, uncomment this
# too:
#d-i lilo-installer/skip boolean true


# This is fairly safe to set, it makes grub install automatically to the MBR
# if no other operating system is detected on the machine.
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true

# This one makes grub-installer install to the MBR if it also finds some other
# OS, which is less safe as it might not be able to boot that other OS.
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true

# Due notably to potential USB sticks, the location of the MBR can not be
# determined safely in general, so this needs to be specified:
d-i grub-installer/bootdev  string /dev/sda
# To install to the first device (assuming it is not a USB stick):
#d-i grub-installer/bootdev  string default

# Alternatively, if you want to install to a location other than the mbr,
# uncomment and edit these lines:
#d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean false
#d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean false
#d-i grub-installer/bootdev  string (hd0,1)
# To install grub to multiple disks:
#d-i grub-installer/bootdev  string (hd0,1) (hd1,1) (hd2,1)

# Optional password for grub, either in clear text
#d-i grub-installer/password password r00tme
#d-i grub-installer/password-again password r00tme
# or encrypted using an MD5 hash, see grub-md5-crypt(8).
#d-i grub-installer/password-crypted password [MD5 hash]

# Use the following option to add additional boot parameters for the
# installed system (if supported by the bootloader installer).
# Note: options passed to the installer will be added automatically.
#d-i debian-installer/add-kernel-opts string nousb

### Finishing up the installation
# During installations from serial console, the regular virtual consoles
# (VT1-VT6) are normally disabled in /etc/inittab. Uncomment the next
# line to prevent this.
#d-i finish-install/keep-consoles boolean true

# Avoid that last message about the install being complete.
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note

# This will prevent the installer from ejecting the CD during the reboot,
# which is useful in some situations.
#d-i cdrom-detect/eject boolean false

# This is how to make the installer shutdown when finished, but not
# reboot into the installed system.
#d-i debian-installer/exit/halt boolean true
# This will power off the machine instead of just halting it.
#d-i debian-installer/exit/poweroff boolean true

### Preseeding other packages
# Depending on what software you choose to install, or if things go wrong
# during the installation process, it's possible that other questions may
# be asked. You can preseed those too, of course. To get a list of every
# possible question that could be asked during an install, do an
# installation, and then run these commands:
#   debconf-get-selections --installer > file
#   debconf-get-selections >> file



### Ubiquity options
ubiquity ubiquity/summary string empty
# reboot automatically, add 'noprompt' to the kernel command line
ubiquity ubiquity/use_nonfree boolean true
ubiquity ubiquity/reboot boolean true
#ubiquity languagechooser/language-name select English
#ubiquity countrychooser/shortlist select US
ubiquity localechooser/supported-locales en_US.UTF-8
ubiquity console-keymaps-at/keymap select us
ubiquity ubiquity/edubuntu-addon_fallback_install booolean false
ubiquity ubiquity/edubuntu-addon_ltsp_install booolean false
ubiquity ubiquity/edubuntu-addon_ltsp_interface select eth0
ubiquity ubiquity/install/generate-blacklist multiselect ubuntu-edu-preschool ubuntu-edu-primary ubuntu-edu-tertiary

#### Advanced options
### Running custom commands during the installation
# d-i preseeding is inherently not secure. Nothing in the installer checks
# for attempts at buffer overflows or other exploits of the values of a
# preconfiguration file like this one. Only use preconfiguration files from
# trusted locations! To drive that home, and because it's generally useful,
# here's a way to run any shell command you'd like inside the installer,
# automatically.

# This first command is run as early as possible, just after
# preseeding is read.
#d-i preseed/early_command string anna-install some-udeb
# This command is run immediately before the partitioner starts. It may be
# useful to apply dynamic partitioner preseeding that depends on the state
# of the disks (which may not be visible when preseed/early_command runs).
#d-i partman/early_command \
#       string debconf-set partman-auto/disk "$(list-devices disk | head -n1)"
# This command is run just before the install finishes, but when there is
# still a usable /target directory. You can chroot to /target and use it
# directly, or use the apt-install and in-target commands to easily install
# packages and run commands in the target system.
#d-i preseed/late_command string apt-install zsh; in-target chsh -s /bin/zsh
d-i preseed/late_command string apt-install openssh-server
```

How can I answer the Edubuntu installation options for gnome fallback, LTSP, and installed educational packages? Also, the keyboar layout is asked for (fixed in updated isolinux/txt.cfg).

The additional package openssh-server does not install. UPDATE: it works now with `ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string in-target apt-get -y install openssh-server;`

I'd also like to set the hostname based on the asset tag with something like

```
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string $(cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_asset_tag)
```

UPDATE: I was able to set the hostname with the following commands after `ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string`

```
if [ "$(cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_asset_tag)" != "" ]; then \
    in-target hostname $(cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_asset_tag) ;\
    in-target sed -i "1s/.*/$(cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_asset_tag)/" /etc/hostname ;\
    in-target sed -i "2s/.*/127.0.1.1\t$(cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_asset_tag)/" /etc/hosts ;\
else \
    in-target hostname $(cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_name) ;\
    in-target sed -i "1s/.*/$(cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_name)/" /etc/hostname ;\
    in-target sed -i "2s/.*/127.0.1.1\t$(cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_name)/" /etc/hosts ;\
fi;
```

UPDATE: I am able to remove packages with `ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string in-target apt-get -y purge unity-scope-yahoostock` but this seems inefficient since it removes packages just after being installed. Does anyone know a way of excluding packages? The Debian `d-i pkgsel/exclude string unity-scope-yahoostock` does not seem to work here with Ubiquity.

Comment: If you want an edubuntu desktop it might be better to start with the edubuntu ISO and not a server version (otherwise you will need to download every DEB that is connected to the metapackage `edubuntu-desktop`. That is a lot of manual work and you can still use this kickstart config.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Rinzwind! That's what I was thinking, but I'm having difficulty getting it working with kickstart.

Comment: This following thread helped me to fix the keyboard selection issue. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2132617

Comment: I'm continuing my work on this and it seems like maybe kickstart is no longer required, and I just need to use a custom preseed file.

Comment: I was able to get openssh-server to install with `ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string in-target apt-get -y install openssh-server;`

Comment: I am able to remove packages with `ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string in-target apt-get -y purge unity-scope-yahoostock` but this seems inefficient since it removes packages just after being installed. Does anyone know a way of excluding packages? The Debian `d-i pkgsel/exclude string unity-scope-yahoostock` does not seem to work here with Ubiquity.

Comment: You will get more attention if you edit it into your question ;) As far as I remember delete does not work in Ubuntu. I solved most of those with a post install script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure out all of my issues except for preseeding the Edubuntu-specific questions, so I am going to resort to  an Ubuntu vanilla install with the following customizations. I will be installing the Edubuntu packages and setting more things up with bash scripts that I will run from SSH.

- Keyboard layout is set with `keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=us and console-setup/ask_detect=false` boot parameters
- Packages are removed with `ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string in-target apt-get -y purge package`
- Packages are installed with `ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string in-target apt-get -y install openssh-server;`
- I was able to set the hostname with commands after `ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string` (see EBA.seed below)

isolinux/isolinux.cfg

```
# D-I config version 2.0
include menu.cfg
default vesamenu.c32
prompt 0
timeout 50
ui gfxboot bootlogo
```

isolinux/txt.cfg

```
default unattended-EBA-install
label unattended-EBA-install
  menu label ^Install for EBA unattended
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/EBA.seed keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=us and console-setup/ask_detect=false boot=casper automatic-ubiquity noprompt initrd=/casper/initrd.lz --
label live
  menu label ^Try Ubuntu without installing
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --
label live-install
  menu label ^Install Ubuntu
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --
label check
  menu label ^Check disc for defects
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi
  append  boot=casper integrity-check initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --
label memtest
  menu label Test ^memory
  kernel /install/mt86plus
label hd
  menu label ^Boot from first hard disk
  localboot 0x80
```

preseed/EBA.seed

```
#### Custom Preseed for EBA
### by Kevin 
### Ubuntu/Edubuntu 14.04
##################################################################################



### General
###################

# Preseed empty to avoid the summary page
ubiquity ubiquity/summary string empty
# reboot automatically, add 'noprompt' to the kernel command line
ubiquity ubiquity/reboot boolean true



### Localization
####################
# Preseeding only locale sets language, country and locale.
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US

# Keyboard selection
# Disable automatic (interactive) keymap detection.
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select us

ubiquity languagechooser/language-name select English
ubiquity countrychooser/shortlist select US
ubiquity localechooser/supported-locales en_US.UTF-8
ubiquity console-keymaps-at/keymap select us


### Network configuration
#############################
# Disable network configuration entirely. This is useful for cdrom
# installations on non-networked devices where the network questions,
# warning and long timeouts are a nuisance.
d-i netcfg/enable boolean false

# netcfg will choose an interface that has link if possible. This makes it
# skip displaying a list if there is more than one interface.
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto

# Disable that annoying WEP key dialog.
#d-i netcfg/wireless_wep string
# The wacky dhcp hostname that some ISPs use as a password of sorts.
#d-i netcfg/dhcp_hostname string radish

# If non-free firmware is needed for the network or other hardware, you can
# configure the installer to always try to load it, without prompting. Or
# change to false to disable asking.
d-i hw-detect/load_firmware boolean true

### Mirror settings
# If you select ftp, the mirror/country string does not need to be set.
#d-i mirror/protocol string ftp
#d-i mirror/country string manual
#d-i mirror/http/hostname string http.us.debian.org
#d-i mirror/http/directory string /debian
d-i mirror/http/proxy string http://proxy:8002



### Account setup
####################

# To create a normal user account.
d-i passwd/user-fullname string EBA Tech
d-i passwd/username string eba
d-i passwd/user-password-crypted password ****

### Clock and time zone setup
# Controls whether or not the hardware clock is set to UTC.
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true

# You may set this to any valid setting for $TZ; see the contents of
# /usr/share/zoneinfo/ for valid values.
d-i time/zone string US/Eastern

# Controls whether to use NTP to set the clock during the install
d-i clock-setup/ntp boolean true
# NTP server to use. The default is almost always fine here.
#d-i clock-setup/ntp-server string ntp.example.com



### Partitioning
#####################

d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

# You can choose one of the three predefined partitioning recipes:
# - atomic: all files in one partition
# - home:   separate /home partition
# - multi:  separate /home, /var, and /tmp partitions
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic

# This makes partman automatically partition without confirmation, provided
# that you told it what to do using one of the methods above.
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true



### Base system installation
################################

### Apt setup
# You can choose to install restricted and universe software, or to install
# software from the backports repository.
#d-i apt-setup/backports boolean true
d-i apt-setup/extras boolean true
d-i apt-setup/multiverse boolean true
d-i apt-setup/partner boolean true
d-i apt-setup/restricted boolean true
d-i apt-setup/universe boolean true

# Use non-free packages
ubiquity ubiquity/use_nonfree boolean true

# Policy for applying updates. May be "none" (no automatic updates),
# "unattended-upgrades" (install security updates automatically), or
# "landscape" (manage system with Landscape).
d-i pkgsel/update-policy select unattended-upgrades

### Boot loader installation
# This is fairly safe to set, it makes grub install automatically to the MBR
# if no other operating system is detected on the machine.
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true



### More Fun!
#############################

#ubiquity ubiquity/edubuntu-addon_fallback_install booolean false
#ubiquity ubiquity/edubuntu-addon_ltsp_install booolean false
#ubiquity ubiquity/edubuntu-addon_ltsp_interface select eth0
#ubiquity ubiquity/install/generate-blacklist multiselect ubuntu-edu-preschool ubuntu-edu-primary ubuntu-edu-tertiary

# Install/remove packages, set hostname, install wifi drivers
ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string \
in-target apt-get -y install openssh-server; \
in-target apt-get -y purge unity-scope-imdb unity-scope-musicstores unity-scope-zotero unity-scope-click-autopilot \
unity-scope-deviantart unity-scope-gallica unity-scope-gdocs unity-scope-github unity-scope-googlenews \
unity-scope-launchpad unity-scope-mediascanner unity-scope-onlinemusic unity-scope-openweathermap \
unity-scope-soundcloud unity-scope-sshsearch unity-scope-yahoostock unity-lens-photos unity-lens-video \
unity-scope-audacious unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks unity-scope-clementine unity-scope-click unity-scope-colourlovers \
unity-scope-gdrive unity-scope-gmusicbrowser unity-scope-gourmet unity-scope-guayadeque unity-scope-mediascanner2 \
unity-scope-musique unity-scope-openclipart unity-scope-texdoc unity-scope-tomboy unity-scope-video-remote \
unity-scope-virtualbox unity-scope-yelp unity-webapps-service account-plugin-ubuntuone ubuntu-purchase-service \
deja-dup indicator-messages empathy gwibber thunderbird transmission-gtk pidgin; \
if [ "$(cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_asset_tag)" != "" ]; then \
    in-target hostname $(cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_asset_tag) ;\
    in-target sed -i "1s/.*/$(cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_asset_tag)/" /etc/hostname ; \
    in-target sed -i "2s/.*/127.0.1.1\t$(cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_asset_tag)/" /etc/hosts; \
else \
    in-target hostname $(cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_name) ;\
    in-target sed -i "1s/.*/$(cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_name)/" /etc/hostname ;\
    in-target sed -i "2s/.*/127.0.1.1\t$(cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_name)/" /etc/hosts; \
fi; \
if [ lspci -d 14e4:4315 ]; then \
    in-target apt-get -qq install firmware-b43-installer || in-target apt-get -qq install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer; \
fi;
```