# Can't preseed Ubuntu Desktop installation

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-cd, preseed

I've downloaded Ubuntu Desktop Live media and was unable to preseed installation changing boot args to:

`boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.gz net.ifnames=0 auto-install/enable=true debconf/priority=critical interface=auto preseed/url=http://10.0.0.2/ubuntu-16.04/preseed.cfg`

Live CD booted and downloaded preseed file, but keeps asking all questions for installation.

Comment: It old, but did you make sure your preseed file was accessible?

Comment: Yes, it is. As I told, it can be downloaded, but can't be executed as it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It old, but it may worth consider... Try using alternate ISO, it says here (https://serverfault.com/questions/143296/how-to-get-http-preseed-to-work-correctly-on-ubuntu-10-04-lts-lucid) that preseed don't work with desktop iso

I succeed with server ISO with this boot line :
<kbd>ESC</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd>, then edit boot line with :

**Edit** : Work better with what in **bold**

**install auto=true priority=critical** url=http://IP/path/to/file/filename initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet ---

---

The reason why preseed appear to not working with Desktop ISO seems related to ubuntu installer which for desktop is now Ubiquity

Ref.: [Preseeding does not work properly in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/467804/preseeding-does-not-work-properly-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Ubiquity links:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubiquity
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation

So you may search about that to figure out how to preseed Desktop ISO properly.

Comment: I'll try Server iso instead of Desktop one... TY