# preseed.cfg installed in initrd root not being recognized in Ubuntu installation (17.10 amd64 desktop or server)

Tags: preseed, initrd

I have been using a process for preseeding the initrd in a Debian ISO for some time. I just tried the same process for desktop and server variants of Ubuntu 17.10 ISOs, and everything looks fine until I boot into it and see absolutely no indication that the installer sees the `preseed.cfg` I placed in its initrd. For example, the installer asks me what language/locale first thing, even though my `preseed.cfg` has:

```
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US.UTF-8
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i keyboard-configuration/layoutcode string us
d-i debian-installer/keymap select us
d-i keymap select us
d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select us
```

I looked through all the F* key options and could not find any option comparable to the Debian Installer's "Automated Install", which decompresses the initrd and looks for/uses the `preseed.cfg` at its root to answer, potential, all installer questions. [The Ubuntu preseeding docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/apbs01.html) confirm that Ubuntu preseeding is supposed to work the same way, saying that:

> …the point at which the preconfiguration file is loaded and processed. For initrd preseeding this is right at the start of the installation, before the first question is even asked.

Does anyone have any helpful hints for what might be going wrong based on the differences between Ubuntu ISOs and Debian ISOs, and the process of preseeding them via initrd?

These pages ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/796145/cant-preseed-ubuntu-desktop-installation), [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/143296/how-to-get-http-preseed-to-work-correctly-on-ubuntu-10-04-lts-lucid), and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/467804/preseeding-does-not-work-properly-in-ubuntu-14-04)) indicate that newer desktop ISOs have been reported to not be preseedable, and that the server ISOs should work "better". So, I downloaded 17.04 (and 17.10) server, repeated my test with that, and got the same behavior.

FTR, the process for embedding the `preseed.cfg` in the initrd I'm using was taken from [the Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed/EditIso). Specifically, I'm using the "isofiles" approach, which is to mount the ISO (I'm using udevil), copy the files to local storage, then [add preseed file to the initrd](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed/EditIso#Adding_a_Preseed_File_to_the_Initrd).

Like I said, this process works great for Debian ISOs, but does not appear to work at all for any of the desktop or server Ubuntu ISOs I've tried.

The [Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/armhf/apbs02.html) confirms that my assumption is valid:

> If you are using initrd preseeding, you only have to make sure a file named `preseed.cfg` is included in the root directory of the initrd. The installer will automatically check if this file is present and load it.

The next thing I tried was to compare my `preseed.cfg` with [the official example Ubuntu preseed file](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/example-preseed.txt) to see if there's some problem with d-i and Ubuntu installers using/supporting different preseed directives. I didn't find much difference. To be sure, I installed, verbatim, the [the official example Ubuntu preseed file](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/example-preseed.txt) in the initrd of the 17.10 server ISO, and the resulting installer still requires human to answer the questions as if there was no preseed at all.

Comment: OK folks, I have repeated my test with ubuntu-17.10.1-server-amd64.iso, and am getting the same result. I have updated the title and issue description.

Comment: Rinzwind, would you please vote to remove this post from "on hold" status, now that it's no longer specific to 17.04? It's been updated to reflect that it is related to 17.10, and also I've deleted my "answers", compiled them into the OP.

Comment: Have you looked at https://askubuntu.com/questions/806820/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu-desktop-16-04-1-lts

Comment: Thank Terrance. His approach isn't what I'm looking for, but Niklas posted a link there to his approach which is identical to my Debian preseed initrd one, plus a little extra magic that mine was missing. He patches grub.cfg and isolinux.cfg to add an "unattended install" boot menu default item that explicitly uses the preseed file. I'm eager to try this approach out, communicate with Niklas, and will report back here if this leads to a real answer to my question. https://github.com/core-process/linux-unattended-installation

Comment: @timblaktu Did you ever figure out how to get this working? I'm trying with 18.04 server and it doesn't seem to want to use my preseed file.

Comment: I tried it with 18.04 server as well. The preseed file *is* used for later questions (e.g. hostname), but not for the initial language questions. That is, I get the same behaviour when I put preseed.cfg into intird.gz as if I simply use the file method (overwrite preseed/ubuntu-server.seed).

Comment: Sorry for the delay.. Ive been off in another universe.. don't have the full answer yet but I can say that yes I got it working (with 17.04, will try 18 soon) but only by using Niklas' idea of customizing the boot menu to force unattended install. Also, I think I'm going to consider shifting my process to use netboot/mini.iso releases exclusively since they appear to work the same for all versions. This consistency is invaluable for configuration management Automation..

Answer (score 1):

On server, to get the lang questions answered, you have add `auto=true` as an option to boot menu.

Here is an example of a pxe menu using `auto=true` (grub menu should be similar):

```
label install
    menu default
    menu label ^Preseed Install
    kernel ubuntu-installer/amd64/linux
    append auto=true vga=normal initrd=ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz
```

Taken from https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed#Loading_the_preseeding_file_from_a_webserver:

> The "auto" command launches the installation in the automated mode, where the configuration of hostname, locale and keymap are postponed so that they can be answered from the preseed file loaded from the network. You could use "install url=..." but you'd have to answer these questions manually, regardless of what you have in the preseed config. If a server path isn't specified the path 'd-i//preseed.cfg' will be tried, for example d-i/stretch/preseed.cfg. Note that network configuration options (netcfg/*) cannot be applied via a network-loaded preseed.cfg file, as the network must be configured before the preseed file can be fetched. If network configuration options must be declared, needed options have be passed as kernel options (eg netcfg/choose_interface=eth0).